# MATLAB: how to find indices of cells which have length greater than threshold?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

Suppose I have a cell array defined as follows:

```
A = {[1:6],[1:4], [1:6],[1:4],[1:4],[1:6] };
```

And I want to find the indices of cells with length greater than threshold,
I thought this might work:

```
I = cellfun(@(x) find(length(A)>threshold), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

but it doesn't (it returns a 1x6 cell containing all 1's)

If anyone could help, it would be appreciated!

Thanks in Advance,

N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
I = find(cellfun(@(x)(length(x)>threshold), A))
```

You want `find` to be outside of the `cellfun`. `cellfun` is going to return a logical array of if the element of `A` is greater than `threshold` or not. You don't need the `'UniformOutput', false` bit because you're returning a boolean for each cell, so the output is uniform.

Lastly you had `length(A)` but that's the number of cells in `A` where as you actually want the length of the vector in each cell which is given by `x` in your code

e.g.

```
A = {[1:6], [1:4], [1:6], [1:4], [1:4], [1:6]};  
thresold = 5;
I = find(cellfun(@(x)(length(x)>threshold), A))

I =

   1   3   6
```